# No menu bar in gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I installed the maximus and the gnome-shell-extension-window-buttons to get Unity like buttons and after that menu bar options like File, Edit and View is not showing up. So I removed the maximus and gnome-shell-extension-window-buttons, but there was no change.

I tried all the shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> and many more.

Answer (score 1):

Just open `dconf-editor`, if you do not have install it `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`. Look for "org" there uncheck the "enabled in the global menu". Restart shell or the system and you will get back the menu.